# Samoa Standard Time (SST) in .NET 4.6.2

Tags: c#, .net, timezone

From https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/sst, the time zone is UTC -11. However, when I get timezone info from .NET. It is the UTC +13.

```
    var timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Samoa Standard Time");
```

timeZoneInfo is UTC +13.

How can I get the correct time zone info of Samoa Standard Time (SST) in .Net

Comment: Samoa uses UTC+13:00 as standard time and UTC+14:00 as daylight saving time, which it observes during summer in the Southern Hemisphere. Until the end of 2011, Samoa fell east of the International Date Line, observing UTC−11:00 (UTC−10:00 during daylight saving time). Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Samoa)

Comment: Hi @TravisSchettler, do you mean it is a bug in .Net? because it is returning UTC +13 for Samoa time

Comment: No, I think .Net is returning it correctly, the website you listed has it wrong. For American Samoa, which is UTC-11, use the "UTC-11" time zone id.

Comment: Actually the website link is correct, it is just referring to the abbreviation used by American Samoa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Samoa (officially [The Independent State of Samoa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samoa)) and [American Samoa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Samoa) are in two different time zones, on opposite sides of the international date line.

[image: Map of the Samoa Islands]
*Image source: Wikimedia Commons*

- The Independent State of Samoa [observes UTC+13 during standard time and UTC+14 during daylight saving time](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/samoa/apia).

  - Its Windows time zone identifier is `"Samoa Standard Time"`
  - Its IANA time zone identifier is `"Pacific/Apia"`
- American Samoa [observes UTC-11 the whole year](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/usa/pago-pago).

  - Its Windows time zone identifier is `"UTC-11"`
  - Its IANA time zone identifier is `"Pacific/Pago_Pago"`

As always:

- Use Windows identifiers with .NET Framework and .NET Core when running on Windows.
- Use IANA identifiers with .NET Core when running on Linux.
- Use the [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter) library to use either form of identifier on either platform.